# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.jpountz.lz4.LZ4BlockOutputStream

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Started my sample Scala Spark program using Scala Eclipse IDE. The program is a simple word Count where I have created a simple text file without compression. While running the code as Scala Application got the error

"Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.jpountz.lz4.LZ4BlockOutputStream" while executing sc.textFile("word.txt")

My Code

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import net.jpountz.lz4.LZ4BlockOutputStream

object WordCount {
  def main (args: Array[String]) = {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("WordCount").setMaster("local")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val test = sc.textFile("word.txt")
    //test.flatMap{line => line.split(" ")}.saveAsTextFile("wordCount.txt")

    //.map{word => (word,1)}.reduceByKey(_ + _).saveAsTextFile("wordCount.txt")
  }
}
```

Running on my local Windows machine. Is this an issue with my POM.xml?

Comment: I don't see the need of that package in the code that you have shared...

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue when reading a CSV file from spark context. It was a bit tricky to track down, but I was able to resolve by viewing the dependency tree.  As it turns out, deep in the bowels of spark, it was invoking a constructor on LZ4BlockInputStream that exists in the updated lz4 library, org.lz4-java-1.4. The issue was it was pulling in the older version lz4, net.jpountz.lz4 (1.3), due to a different outdated dependency.

Comment: same here with spark 2.3, in my case offender was quite fresh - spark-sql-kafka-0-10:2.3.0

Comment: Any hint on how you viewed the dependency tree would help. Also, how you configured it to pull in the right lib.

Answer (score 0):

for me this library resolved my issue :

```
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.jpountz.lz4/lz4/1.3.0
```